# Teams losing games despite scoring runs

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

How many times has an MLB team lost a game after scoring 10 or more runs?

Answer (score 1):

This happens fairly frequently.  For example, just looking around briefly, the [Chicago White Sox lost to the New York Mets 11-10](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/NYN/NYN202307180.shtml) a month ago or so, and the [New York Mets lost to the Colorado Rockies 11-10 as well](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/COL/COL202305280.shtml) earlier this season. The [Giants lost to the Padres 16-11](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/SDN/SDN202304290.shtml) early in the season, but [beat the Reds 11-10](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CIN/CIN202307180.shtml); the Reds had of course only recently [beaten the Braves by a similar 11-10 margin](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CIN/CIN202306230.shtml).